Is there a way to extend an interface with Jakarta endpoints as a Quarkus Rest Client without adding any additional endpoints?
I'm trying to create and Inject a RestClient interface into my Quarkus application. This rest client interface extends another interface from an external library where all my endpoints are configured. I am on Quarkus 3 and am using the quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson library.
This is the rest client
@Path("path/path")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "my-service")
public interface IMyRestService extends IServiceEndpoints {
}

This is the external interface
@Path("path/path")
public interface IServiceEndpoints{
    
    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Consumes({"text/plain"})
    @Produces({"text/plain"})
    String doAction(String description);

    <more endpoints>
}

When I try to run this, I get a unsatisfied dependency build error. I can solve this error by implementing an endpoint in my rest client layer. I was wondering if there's a way to fix this error without having to add an (in my case nonsensical) endpoint to my rest client. I know ideally that I would just put endpoints into the rest client without the library layer, but that's not how this project is structured unfortunately.

Is the external library under your control?

@geoand Yes it is

In that case try adding an empty META-INF/beans.xml file under src/main/resources of that library and build it again.

I was in the same spot. I wanted to define the endpoint itself in my own external library as it can be easily reused in multiple projects and wanted only extend the interface to make integration-specific adjustments.
import com.example.core.rest_client.EntityService;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import java.util.Map;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "api")
public interface DefaultEntityService
        extends EntityService {}

I ran also into the unsatisfied dependency exception. The problem was that the Quarkus Runtime was unaware of the the EntityService. So I needed to index the external library specifically in the application.properties.
quarkus.index-dependency.api.group-id=com.exmaple
quarkus.index-dependency.api.artifact-id=core 

Afterwards I was able to inject the extended Rest Service and use the underlying endpoint.
@RestClient
DefaultEntityService entityService;

Hope this helps.
